# How to get Braintree payment client token?

Tags: paypal, payment, braintree

i created sandbox account login successfully but not find client token where it is.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njD8D.png)

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Full disclosure, I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, I recommend contacting [support](https://www.braintreepayments.com/contact)</sub>

Braintree is a full-stack payments solution. In order to pass a client token on your client-side, you'll need to first [generate a client token](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/client-token/generate/ruby) on your server, then pass it to your client. As an example, here's how you'd generate one in Ruby:

```
@client_token = gateway.client_token.generate
```

Alternatively, you can use a [tokenization key](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/authorization/tokenization-key/javascript/v3) for client authentication. This is a static key with reduced privileges, but still can authenticate your client to work with Braintree's servers. You can find your tokenization key in the Control Panel.

I recommend reviewing the [Getting Started documentation][get], as there is a lot of great information and images to help illustrate getting Braintree integrated. You could also check out some of the [end-to-end examples](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/example-integrations) for full-context of an example integration.

Comment: Hi David - Not sure if it's the best place to ask but is it possible to use Braintree without having a server at all? Thank you